# Stop thread on Android

Tags: android

I have this code for changing the screen color.

But I don't know how to stop this thread:

```
lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (finalStatus < 1) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    colorHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(flag)
                            {
                             lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                             flag = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                 flag = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

I tried to put:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"STOP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finalStatus=1;
                lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
```

and the thread stopped, but the screen is red, or blue, I need black.

Moreover, how to start this thread after I have stopped it?

Comment: There is no service there, just some threads. If you want to get out of the while just change finalStatus to one. Is there something that I'm missing ? The code updating the background doesn't have any loop so will finish right away.

Comment: Two problems: 1.  You're changing UI elements in a separate thread.  This will crash eventually. 2.  You're setting the background to black as soon as you set `finalStatus` to 1. The thread will finish AFTER you set the background to black but before the thread leaves it will change the background back to whatever color it should be thus overwriting the color change.

Comment: @DeeV OP is using a handler to handle changing UI from another thread. That's fine. I agree that what you point out in #2 is probably the main problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the scenario for getting a background blue or red but let's assume it's when you set the finalStatus to 1. In order to avoid changing the background and still exiting the thread you can set it to a different value in your button click listener, let's say to 111. Adding the following condition before colorHandler.post will solve the issue:

```
if (finalStatus == 111) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put that `lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` code after the While loop in the outer thread run() method. and dont forget to use the handler for the same since other than UI thread wont update the UI.

Comment: That would have unexpected effects. The first of them being you don't know which thread would be run first - the one setting the background to black or a different color. Depending on the order of execution one of them would always be overwritten.